# responsive positioning of elements on top of a centered element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image that is centered. On top of it, I want to position various clickable points. I'm trying to do this in the most responsive way possible, but so far, I've had no luck. Can anyone lend some insight, please? I don't want to get marked down for this, but I'm having trouble finding an answer.

This is my HTML:

```
<img src="images/Map.png" id="map" />
<img class="down" id="location1" src="images/square.png"/>
<img class="down" id="location2" src="images/square.png"/>
<img class="down" id="location3" src="images/square.png"/>
<img class="down" id="location4" src="images/square.png"/>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#map {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    width:700px;
    margin-top:130px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 515px;
}
.down {
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#location1 {
    top: 230px;
    left: 39%;
}
#location2 {
    top: 240px;
    left: 38%;
}
#location3 {
    top: 410px;
    left: 60%;
}
#location4 {
    top: 390px;
    left: 59%;
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with in particular?

Comment: The positions aren't accurate if my screen resolution changes.

Comment: You would need to make the widths of the objects as responsive as the left positioning. Do you have a live example that we can work with?

Comment: I mean, the positions of the locations on top of the map aren't accurate if my screen resolution changes.

Comment: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to wrap all that HTML in a div, and use position:relative on that div.  As of now, you have position:relative on the image, but the image is not the parent of those squares so position:absolute will not be with respect to that image.

```
<div style="position:relative; width:700px; margin:0 auto;">
    <img src="images/Map.png" id="map" />
    <img class="down" id="location1" src="images/square.png"/>
    <img class="down" id="location2" src="images/square.png"/>
    <img class="down" id="location3" src="images/square.png"/>
    <img class="down" id="location4" src="images/square.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That does seem to be working in every browser but IE (I have IE7--I'm at work, so I can't update it). Is there some trick to make IE behave, do you know, please?

Comment: I don't have access to IE7 to test, but what exactly do you see happening there?

Comment: The little squares aren't where I positioned them.

Comment: where are they?  try positioning the first one in the top left corner (top:0; left:0) and make sure it shows up in the top left on other browsers.  Then tell me where it appears on IE7.